# Why does passing a function with parenthesis to 'addListener' cause it to only fire once?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, event-listener

In my chrome extension, I have two event listeners and a function `updateTabs`:

```
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(updateTabs());
chrome.tabs.onUpdated.addListener(updateTabs);

function updateTabs() {...}
```

Why does the `onActivated` listener fire only once, while the `onUpdated` listener works as expected?

From what I understand, the parenthesis in `updateTabs()` means that the function is called at that point. However, wouldn't that mean `updateTabs()` is still called whenever the `onActivated` listener is fired? It seems like the event listener is being removed somehow and I do not understand why.

Comment: Why would that mean that it's called whenever the listener is activated? You said it yourself: the function is called at the point when `addListener()` is called, not when the event occurs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first call is equivalent to this:

```
let temp = updateTabs();
chrome.tabs.onActivated.addListener(temp);
```

When written this way, it should be clear that the function is only called once *before* the listener is added. And when you call `addListener`, you're not providing a function for it to call when the `onActivated` event occurs, you're passing whatever `updateTabs` returned.

Answer (score 0):

onActivated listener fire only once. But it's not because of the event. It's because the JS interpreter when reading your "definition" at this point executes/calls the function only the result is then attached to the listener.